# Finding the prime factors of $2^{14}+3^{14}$ by hand

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I need to find the prime factors of $2^{14}+3^{14}$ by hand (this was given in an exam at my university, so this is the motivation - I decided to state this because it may look unjustified to try to factor such a big number).

I began by noticing that $2^{14}+3^{14}=4^7+9^7=13\cdot 369181$ after applying a well known formula. So, it all boils down to finding the prime factors of $369181$.

Let $p$ be such a prime. Obviously, $p$ is not $2$ since our number is odd. We have $p|2^{14}+3^{14}$, so $2^{14} \equiv -3^{14} (p)$, where $(p)$ is shorthand for $\operatorname{mod} p$, so $2^{28}\equiv 3^{28}(p)$. Since $p$ is not equal to $2$, $2$ has an inverse modulo $p$, call it $2^{-1}$. Thus, $(3\cdot 2^{-1})^{14}\equiv -1(p)$  and $(3\cdot 2^{-1})^{28}\equiv 1(p)$. This easily implies that the order of $3\cdot 2^{-1}$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is $28$. So, $28$ divides $\varphi(p)=p-1$, that is $p=1+28t$ for some $t\in \mathbb{N}$.

This is where things got messy. I could only continue by taking the square root of $369181$, which is $607$ point something, so I have to check whether $369181$ is divisible by any prime of the form $28t+1$ that is less than $607$. These primes are $29, 113, 197, 281, 337, 421$ and $449$ if I didnt make any mistakes.

Now, I could do the computations, but they are really long. I wonder if there is some neat way to avoid doing this.

Comment: You might already know the answer: $369181$ is prime. I doubt whether there exists a better method. There is obviously no general (fast) method for factorizing $a^{14}+b^{14}$ for arbitrary $a,b$.

Comment: @WhatsUp, a partial factorization is $a^{14}+b^{14}=(a^2 + b^2) (a^{12} - a^{10} b^2 + a^8 b^4 - a^6 b^6 + a^4 b^8 - a^2 b^{10} + b^{12})$. That's where $13=2^2+3^2$ comes from.

Comment: @lhf Of course, I meant the complete factorization.

Comment: Note that your argument that $p=1+28t$ relies on the fact that $(3\cdot2^{-1})^2\not\equiv-1\pmod{p}$, or equivalently, that $p\neq13$.

Comment: I'd like to learn something new... what is the well known formula?

Comment: @lesath82 The well-known formula is written above, but just in case : $x^k+y^k$ is divisible by $x+y$ whenever $k$ is odd, and the proof of that is basically the fact that $\frac{x^k+y^k}{x+y} = \frac{x^k - (-y)^k}{x-(-y)}$, and then you can focus on $\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}$, which can be written as $x^{n-1}\frac{1 - (\frac{y}{x})^n}{1-\frac yx}$. At this point, one uses the "summation of a geometric series" idea , usually learned in high school, to see that $\frac{1 - (\frac{y}{x})^n}{1-\frac yx} = 1+\frac yx + \ldots + \left(\frac yx\right)^{n-1}$, and then you work backwards.

Comment: I just wanted to comment that each of these long divisions is not that long. I don't know how much time you are expected to complete the question in, but if I was in your position I would probably do them and not feel too bad about it. They take 1-2 minutes each.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Oh, thank you, how can I have missed that! I must definitely stop goofing around at 1 a.m...

Comment: @lesath82 I thought you genuinely did not know it, to be honest! Although that leaves your desire to learn something new incomplete. Perhaps you will need some assistance completing that!

Comment: @Servaes thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to mention that I should have $p\ne 13$ for that to work and I should check by hand the case $p=13$.

Comment: @AlfredYerger yes, that's right, but it still felt pretty long for a 2-hour exam where you have 5 other questions and I was afraid that I may be missing some shortcut.

Comment: If you consider this task to take long , think of the man spending the sundays of three years to factor $2^{67}-1$. This was an anormous task despite the restrictions of the possible prime factors. Apart from the proof by hand that $2^{127}-1$ is prime , perhaps the most impressing calculation that has been done in the pre-computer era.

Comment: It is debatable whether such an exercise should occur in an exam , it is still time consuming and doing such divisions (even if they are in principle easy to do) needs much care without giving additional insights (assuming that electronic help as a table calculator was not allowed).

Comment: @Peter, good point. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207321/how-did-cole-factor-267-1-in-1903 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Nelson_Cole

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have done the best you can at avoiding tedious calculations. You have narrowed down the list of prime divisors to check to just $7$ primes. From here, you can check each of them quite easily by means of long division.

Another way to proceed, is to check whether
$$(3\cdot2^{-1})^{14}\equiv-1\pmod{p},$$
for each of these primes. For the primes with $t$ even, this means $3\cdot2^{-1}$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, and for primes with $t$ odd, this means $3\cdot2^{-1}$ is a quadratic nonresidue mod $p$. So it remains to determine $\left(\frac{6}{p}\right)$ for these primes.

Comment: thanks for the alternative method!